# iterate over array and insert value into JSON url

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am attempting to get a value from an array with a for loop and insert it into a JSON url. Here is the code.

```
myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
    datasetWebId.forEach(function(v) {
        var webId = (v);
        $.getJSON("https://www.twdc/api/" + webId + "/recorded?starttime=*-3d&endtime=*", function(resp) {

            tableData = [];
            resp.Items.forEach(function(item) {
                item.Items.forEach(function(subItem) {
                    tableData.push({
                        'name': item.Name,
                        'Timestamp': subItem.Timestamp,
                        'Value': subItem.Value,
                        'Path': item.Path
                    });
                });
            });

        });
        table.appendRows(tableData);
        doneCallback();
    });

};
```

When it runs it hits the first loop and just skips the rest. There is values in datasetWebId array, so that is no the issue. Can someone spot something out of place?

Comment: please show your json

Comment: Json isn't the problem there is something when with the loop and how Webid is put into the irk. Because it works without that. @PradyutManna

Comment: any error in console? @llerdal

Comment: I think this is another question on [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323), like an AJAX-call (or multiple).

Comment: There is so  much that could be to blame for this. I suspect `CORS` to be the perp.

Comment: If works without Webid, what value has Webid and what value is passed when you don't use it?

Comment: Happy to reopen this if you can edit it to add the JSON as requested, though it looks like you have asked another question about this shortly after this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called `doneCallback` at the end of the first item of datasetWebId array, which is why it never have another iteration.

```
myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
    datasetWebId.forEach(function(v) {
        var webId = (v);
        $.getJSON("https://www.twdc/api/" + webId + "/recorded?starttime=*-3d&endtime=*", function(resp) {

        tableData = [];
        resp.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            item.Items.forEach(function(subItem) {
                tableData.push({
                    'name': item.Name,
                    'Timestamp': subItem.Timestamp,
                    'Value': subItem.Value,
                    'Path': item.Path
                });
            });
        });

    });
    table.appendRows(tableData);
  });
  doneCallback(); //This has been moved.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here. First, we have no idea what "datasetWebId" is. This is your array that you're iterating through to send each AJAX request, no doubt, but if it's quitting after one you should `console.log` the length of this before it runs, to make sure it actually has data to iterate through.

Second. You have 3 (!) nested for-loops. It's not at all shocking there's a weird data leaking issue, as this is one of the major symptoms of a bit too much over-nesting. Not to worry, we've all been there. Throw all of those in separate functions you can test independently, and start running them one at a time. And, don't do anything until you make sure the symbol fire-response of the AJAX is working properly.

Okay, you got this. If you can, post more info on that array, and I'd be happy to send you through a cleaned up interpretation.